# Flex Container CSS : How to center div element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, containers

I have the following HTML/CSS code and I have an issue to center the content inside a flex container. The result is :

[image: ko result]

In my mind, I would like to center the ring inside the flex container AND center the text (temperature) and the CSS animation (arrow) just after the temperature inside the ring animation.

How to do this?

```css
body {
  background-color: #0d74ff;
}

.container {
  padding: 20px;
}

.flexwrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cell {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.loader-ring {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.loader-ring-light {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 0 #ffffff inset;
  animation: rotate-360 6s linear infinite;
}

.loader-text {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.scroll-down {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.scroll-down i {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 0 auto;
  animation: pulse 1.5s 0s infinite normal ease forwards;
  background-image: url("https://jamesmuspratt.com/codepen/img/arrow-down.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes rotate-360 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: 0 auto;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    background-size: 75% auto;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-size: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="flexwrap">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class='loader-ring'>
        <div class='loader-ring-light'></div>
        <div class='loader-ring-track'>
          <div class='loader-text'>26.6&deg;</div>
          <div class="scroll-down"><i></i></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need so many blocks here. You need absolute positioning because elements will need to stack on each other. Also for centering absolutely positioned elements you need this styles

```
.loader-ring,
.loader-ring-track {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Demo:

```css
body {
  background-color: #0d74ff;
}

.container {
  padding: 20px;
}

.cell {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

 /* center absolutely positioned items */
 /* both vertically and horizontally */
.loader-ring,
.loader-ring-track {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.loader-ring-track {
  display: flex; /* new */
}

.loader-ring {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.loader-ring-light {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 0 #ffffff inset;
  animation: rotate-360 6s linear infinite;
}

.loader-text {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.scroll-down {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.scroll-down i {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 0 auto;
  animation: pulse 1.5s 0s infinite normal ease forwards;
  background-image: url("https://jamesmuspratt.com/codepen/img/arrow-down.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes rotate-360 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: 0 auto;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    background-size: 75% auto;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-size: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">

<div class="cell">
  <div class='loader-ring'>
    <div class='loader-ring-light'></div>
    <div class='loader-ring-track'>
      <div class='loader-text'>26.6&deg;</div>
      <div class="scroll-down"><i></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```